# use JSON variable in jQuery to display more JSON variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

This is somewhat pseudo code so EDIT away. I want to make it when the user clicks on a thumb inside `#placeholder` DIV `thumb2` is then displayed inside `#imageLoad` DIV. NOTE: `Thumb` and `thumb2` are JSON items. A lot of people are saying that this can't be done with `getJSON` because it's an asynchronous request. If that is the case, then how can I change my script to support the request? If I am going the wrong way, please provide alternate solutions.

```
$.getJSON('jsonFile.json', function (data) {
    var image1 = "<ul>";
    for (var i in data.items) {
        image1 += "<li><img src=images/items/" + data.items[i].thumb + ".jpg></li>";
    }
    image1 += "</ul>";
    document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML = output;

    var image2 = "<img src=images/items/" + data.items[i].thumb2 + ".jpg>";
    $('li').click(function () {
        document.getElementById("imageLoad").innerHTML = output;
    });
});
```

Here is the external JSON file below (jsonFile.json):

```
{"items":[
    {
        "id":"1",
        "thumb":"01_sm",
        "thumb2":"01_md"
    },
    {
        "id":"2",
        "thumb":"02_sm",
        "thumb2":"02_md"
    }
]}
```

Comment: Did you try the code you posted? At first glance it looks fine, except for the `for..in` loop that should be a regular `for` on `data.items`, and `output` should be `image1` first, then `image2`.

Comment: possible violation of KISS paradigm :P

Comment: Yes, I have this script posted. It prints the Unordered List fine, but the mouseOnclick function doesn't work with those variable. The mouseOnClick only works if I swap the JSON variables for actual elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like the following:

```
$.getJSON('jsonFile.json', function(data)
{
  $("#placeholder").html("");
  var ul = $('<ul></ul>');
  $('#placeholder').append(ul);
  var load = $("#imageLoad");

  for(var i in data.items)
  {
    var li = $('<li></li>');
    ul.append(li);
    var img = $('<img>');
    img.attr("src", "images/items/" + data.items[i].thumb + ".jpg");
    img.click((function(x)
    {
      return function()
      {
        load.html("<img src=images/items/" + data.items[x].thumb2 + ".jpg>");
      }
    })(i));
    li.append(img);
  }
});
```

Main difference is that click-handler is assigned inside the loop, so every handler receives a closure with appropriate reference to thumb2.

Comment: I think you mean `img.click(function(x) { return function(e) { load.html(...) } }(i))`

Comment: @teddybeard You're wrong. You need to pass current i as parameter of executed function, in order to catch it inside the closure. My code is tested.

Comment: Hmm it seems like this actually might work, however right now I am experiencing a bug.. The last list item printed (there are 3 in the JSON file) does not load its thumb2?? The first 2 li's do. Anythoughts? It seems to loose the variable for the 3rd item click.

Comment: @user1644123 That can be a typo in data. Add console.log just to make sure the handler is invoked and has appropriate URL.

Comment: where do I add console.log in the script? Before or after FOR?? Thanks.

Comment: Also, I ran my JSON in JSONLint and found no typos. Any other ideas?

Comment: Stan, thanks you are right. And, no console.log needed. But should I add it anyway? What does it do? Also, can you tell me how fix the delay of the images. Can they be preloaded? And / or is there another method?

Comment: No, `console.log` is only a way of testing, to make sure what is getting called (actually you can place breakpoints in Chrome devtools or FireBug). If you have a delay after a click, this can happen because new image is loading from server. I don't think it's a good idea to preload them all beforehand, because this will lead to unnecessary overheads (some user may not want to view all images) and slow down inital loading even more. I'd suggest to provide a kind of animated progress bar appearing when an image starts loading, and hiding afterwards.

Comment: @Stan I was commenting on the original answer you posted. You were not assigning a closure to the click handler but trying to make a closure inside the handler function. I see that you have revised the code accordingly, however, stackoverflow won't let me remove my down vote. Nice work.

Comment: @teddybeard, that's strange, AFAIK you should be able to unvote any vote (up or down) by clicking the same arrow.

Comment: @stan ah, yes. i was trying to click up arrow before. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this could do the trick:

```
var $placeholder = $('#placeholder'),
    $imageLoad = $('#imageLoad');

$.getJSON('jsonFile.json', function(data) {
    var html = '<ul>';

    $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
        html += '<li><img src=images/items/' + item.thumb + '.jpg></li>';
    });        
    html += '</ul>';

    $placeholder.html(html);
});

$placeholder.on('click','li',function(){    
    $imageLoad.html($(this).html());
});
```

I can't understand the use of `output` since you are not declaring it in anyway. The eventhandler for the `click` event will trigger on all current and future `li` elements of the `$placeholder` which contains the DOM object with an `id` of `placeholder`.

Comment: I tested this and it is now not displaying anything inside #placeholder DIV